# How to get row data from DataGridview after user deleting it

Tags: c#, desktop-application

I'm working in a project for a shop and using DataGridView to store all customer orders and update the total price continuously. I update the price when he order more items easily. When I remove a specific item, I need to know its data to update the total price too.

So I need that row's content to make the change I need.

That's what I use to update the total price when he adds more items:

```
DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow();

row.CreateCells(pill);

row.Cells[2].Value = name;
row.Cells[1].Value = price;
row.Cells[0].Value = quantity;

pill.Rows.Add(row);

totalPrice += price * quantity;
total.Text = totalPrice.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an event called `UserDeletingRow`. It accepts `DataGridViewRowCancelEventArgs` which contains row that user deletes.

What you need to do is to subscribe to this event, and update your price from there.